# display of quiz after choosing number of quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm actually doing up a questionnaire website for my own purpose.
I manage to do a loop but I suppose my sequence of java script is wrong. 
Below is my code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var string ="";
            for(var i=2;i<12;i++){
                string +="<option value='"+i+"'>"+(i-1)+"</option>";
                console.log('test');
            }
            $("#select-question-type").change(function(evt)
            {
                var selected = $(this).val();

                if (selected == "1"){
                    $(".show-qn").show();
                    $(".show-check").hide();
                } else if(selected == '2') {
                    $(".show-check").hide();
                    $(".show-qn").hide();                    
                } else if(selected == '3'){
                    $(".show-check").show();
                    $(".show-qn").hide();
                }

            }).change();


            $("#total_qn_number").html(string);

            $("#total_qn_number").change(function(e){
                console.log("changed");
                var counter = $(this).val();
                var appendString = "";
                console.log(counter);
                for(var x=1;x<counter;x++){
                    appendString+='<br />Question '+x+':<br /><textarea name="question' +x+'" placeholder="Type your question"></textarea><br /><div class="show-qn"><label></label>A1:<input type="text" name="answer1' +x+'" placeholder="Type your 1st option" /><br /><label></label>A2:<input type="text" name="answer2' +x+'" placeholder="Type your 2nd option" /><br /><label></label>A3:<input type="text" name="answer3' +x+'" placeholder="Type your 3rd option" /><br /><label></label>A4:<input type="text" name="answer4' +x+'" placeholder="Type your 4th option" /></div><div class="show-check"><input type="text" name="cb1' +x+'" placeholder="Type your 1st option" /><br /><input type="text" name="cb2' +x+'" placeholder="Type your 2st option" /><br /><input type="text" name="cb3' +x+'" placeholder="Type your 3st option" /><br /><input type="text" name="cb4' +x+'" placeholder="Type your 4st option" /><br /><input type="text" name="noOfCorrectAns' +x+'" placeholder="Type down the no of correct ans." /></div>';
                }
                $("#container").html(appendString);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

It actually works pretty well but the problem lies with the show and hide.
Whenever I choose my select box option, it actually "restart" the whole js itself removing all the .show and .hide functions and I've to re-click the option box for it to display normally. The picture is as below:

Before:

[image: before clicking on choice]

After:

[image: after clicking choice]

And IF i re-choose my number of question, the 'before' picture appear again which will make user irritated.
Is there a way to make it stay like 'After' even if I re-choose my option?

**UPDATE**: 
Link to fiddle:  jsfiddle.net/537vh

Comment: in your code, $("#select-question-type") ends with change(function(){}).change() ... do you need to write change twice?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you meant.
it have to change twice because both needs to change(if i didn't get your question wrongly)

Comment: $("#select-question-type").change(function(evt)
    {var selected = $(this).val();
if (selected == "1"){
                    $(".show-qn").show();
                    $(".show-check").hide();
                } else if(selected == '2') {
                    $(".show-check").hide();
                    $(".show-qn").hide();                    
                } else if(selected == '3'){
                    $(".show-check").show();
                    $(".show-qn").hide();
                }
            }).change();
this has change written twice. What happens when you remove the last  .change() ?

Comment: Um, I don't see the change written twice on the code u copied and pasted.

Comment: If you are referring to the .change(function) and .change(), if i remove the last change, it'll display straight as first pic, instead of second pic.

Comment: hmm.. please can you create a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ and share the link in your question. will make it easier to debug for you and others

Comment: Thanks for the option, this is the link:
http://jsfiddle.net/537vh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IS this what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/m69XP/2/

I put this in a function that gets called on change of both select boxes

```
$("#select-question-type").change(function(evt)
                {
                    var selected = $(this).val();

                    if (selected == "1"){
                        $(".show-qn").show();
                        $(".show-check").hide();
                    } else if(selected == '2') {
                        $(".show-check").hide();
                        $(".show-qn").hide();                    
                    } else if(selected == '3'){
                        $(".show-check").show();
                        $(".show-qn").hide();
                    }
                    else{
                        $(".show-check").hide();
                    }
                }).change();
```

Comment: Nope, it actually works the same as mine.
You try choosing the number of question, after that you choose the question type, after that you re-choose the number of questions again.

It'll go back to the first image(above) which that's not I want.
I want it to show the second image no matter how many numbers of question I chose

Comment: Updating...got what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks in advance. I tried moving around the .change() or even removing them, it won't work. argh~

Comment: I have updated the answer. with the link to the updated fiddle. it's quite close to what you want, but will require some finishing by you.
You can accept the answer if you are satisfied with the solution provided.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for your effort!